# Film with a girl on a flying boat trying to find a missing relative

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've been bothered by this film for about 15+ years, all I can remember is the ending.

The film takes place on a flying boat/ship. It was big and had sails and was made of wood. It used smoke effect clouds, I don't think a lot of CGI. The main character is a girl, trying to find her father or young teenage brother, I know they are both in it.

There is a crew that fights a lot. At the ending it's the boat waiting to leave, at a dock, lots of smoke, love interests and a choice to stay or go. Someone chooses to leave with the boat, because I think they will forget once they go back to their normal lives and they want adventure.

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0486655/?

Comment: Apart from not being animated and the forgetting part, it almost sounds like [Laputa: Castle in the Sky](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092067/).

Comment: Or also like [Bosco Adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosco_Adventure)

Answer (score 4):

Flying boat sounds like [The Adventures of Baron Munchausen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Baron_Munchausen) and there's a young girl as protagonist. I don't recall her looking for her brother, though.

Answer (score 2):

There's an older film, 35 years not 15, **Ópera do Malandro**, in which it's the other way around, it's the flying boat that's searching for the girl. This is a subplot in the film, based on *Pirate Jenny*, part of Kurt Weill and Bertold Brecht's *Three-penny Opera*, in which the girl is lost and the pirates, her relatives, are searching for her, in a sailing ship.

Is that your film? Your film could also be one of the others that are based on *Pirate Jenny*, such as *Dogville*.

Answer (score 0):

It could be

#### [Waterworld](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/waterworld)

A young girl has directions to the last piece of above-water land on Earth tattooed on her back, where her parents live. She wants to get back to her parents; everyone else wants to find the mythical "Dryland". Kevin Costner's character (the Mariner) saves her and the woman who's looking after her, and they head off on his trimaran. Lots of fighting ensues as the Big Bad tries to get her back and find Dryland.

Most of the action takes place on boats, but some key sections also involve travel by balloon, including the final section of getting to Dryland.

The film finishes with the Mariner heading back to sea, because he realises he doesn't belong on land.

It's not a totally bad film. Of course it's derivative of *Mad Max 2*, which was far better. If you're a fan of sailing though, the general opinion is that the star of the film was Costner's trimaran, which was absolutely a thing of beauty. The rest of the film is big-budget meh with 90s FX.

Comment: The film was considered a total flop, but that may be due to higher expectations from Costner.

Comment: That and iirc it barely broke even.

Comment: @Barmar It certainly didn't make much money, and it's certainly not a good film. But I stand by my love for the trimaran!